# Convert string to hex like "88" to 0x88

Tags: c, gtk

I'm using gtk+.How to convert string to hex like char*p="88" to unsigned char s=0x88 .I need to assign string value from table to byte element in array.

Comment: `s = strtol(p, NULL, 16);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Why do people always comment such answers instead of answering the question properly.  SO depends on the correct usage, so the questions is marked as answered, and the OP only can accept answers, not comments.

Comment: @Alfe: An answer which isn't formal/perfect is many times nitpicked or downvoted, thus, instead of doing all the formalities, people just comment and let others take the cake.

Comment: @legends2k Or "fastest gun in the west". It's easiest to give the quick and dirty answer in the comments while you formalize it into an answer. If others say you deserve the credit, that's basically an invitation to give you all the time you need. Otherwise, it's as you said, someone who's better at writing answers can take the credit.

Comment: @Alfe I explore the intent of the questioner in the comments for the time being if the question is not clear. Also, usually in the case of questions and answers is of little value.

Comment: It is most likely a duplicate question. But it will take more effort to find a duplicate link than to write an answer, so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdint.h> // better integer types
#include <stdlib.h> // strtoul, NULL

const char* p = "88";
uint8_t s = (uint8_t) strtoul(p, NULL, 16);
```

Comments:

- Pointers to string literals should always be declared as const.
- For small integer types, the types in stdint.h are preferred, as they are safer than the default integer types (such as `int`).
- There are a number of functions that can convert a string to an integer. The most flexible ones are the "strto..." functions: `strtol` (string to singed long), `strtoul` (string to unsigned long), `strtod` (string to double) and so on. There exist no such conversion functions for integer types smaller than `long`.
- You want the result to be unsigned, so it is good practice to use the `strtoul` function, to prevent various implicit type promotion problems.
- Since the function returns an `unsigned long`, cast it to the intended type, which is `uint8_t`.
- The 3rd parameter of the function tells which base you want the number conversion to have. 2 for binary, 8 for octal, 10 for decimal or 16 for hexadecimal.

Comment: Also note that there is a lazy/easy standard version of `strtol(..., 10)`, which is called `atoi` (ASCII to int). That function is a standardized wrapper around `strtol`. Some compilers have a corresponding function `itoa` (int to ASCII), but that one is _not_ standard C.

Comment: With C++11 the standard version of `itoa` is `to_string`.

Comment: @legends2k This is tagged C. C++ is a different programming language.

Comment: In deed it is; an overlook on my part.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char *end = NULL;
s = strtol(p, &end, 16);
//check errno here
if (p==end)
    printf ("I smell fish - most likely something is wrong.");
```

Keep in mind that base is limited to the range of `[2-36]`

To my knowledge there is no `glib/gtk+` specific wrapper fro `strtol`

See `man strtol` for a complete example.